# How to define multiple main pages in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to have multiple main index pages that should be accessable independent from each other. Means: there is no global page providing static links to all of the main index pages. Each should live on its own:

```
WebContent/indexA.html
WebContent/indexB.html
...
```

Question: how can I write an `angularjs` controller that shows these pages, if I do not call the`*.html` extension, but a get-query on that path?

I want to be able to call:

```
localhost/indexA?param=123
localhost/indexB?test=xyz
```

Each of them will then map to their own html page, and the request params are to be processed by the controller of that page only.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Comment: multiple main pages = potential design flaw ? Why you need to do this ? Or what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Why not? The pages will show content that differs completely among these pages. Some users will get the link to /indexA, others will get the link to /indexB. This is because each user is only interested in one derivation of the content. Thus there is no main page linking to all possible "main" pages.

Comment: So your goal is to show _different_ main page based on criteria , right ? As it is not clear from your question

Comment: Well, the *criteria* is actually already the path. If the user launches /indexN, the main page is clear to be indexN.html. The query params are just fields to be processed within the different main pages. Sorry if I was inadequate.

Comment: So, to get it (now my understanding is loose) - users opens `localhost/indexA?param=123` it gets some HTML, on top of this HTML angular controller (Same for all of them) is running, correct ?

Comment: Yes, there exists an ControllerA that controls indexA mainpage only, and a ControllerB that controls indexB main page only.

Comment: How are you serving your web content? I don't think what you are trying to do is difficult. It doesn't matter whether you access the pages through a link on a "global" page or enter the URL directly. Your app router should map each route (url path) to the required controller and view template.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, that you need to use same code (Controller) on different HTML pages, loaded with different URLs.

First option is to use directives to encapsulate same logical parts (Each directive can have attributes, you can provide them in HTML, depend on how is your HTML structured). This is good, when you do not have any routing in your app now.

Second option is to use ui-router with HTML5 routing (then you can pick parameters from URL), this will probably require you to move more logic on frontend, but it is clear solution, if this is not small project.

Next option is to put required parameters into script tag of HTML and then load them from your controller - this is dirty, but quick way of solving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ui-router` for the same.
Based on the parameters you pass, you can choose the active state where you can have your own controller and templateURL